# docker push has integrity failures from a given commit and onwards

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I'm trying to push a docker container to a private registry on the Google Cloud Platform:

`gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/<project-name>/<container-name>`

and a checksum fails:

```
e9a19ae6509f: Pushing [========================================>          ] 610.9 MB/752.4 MB
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Layer already exists 
...
xxxxxxxxxxxx: Layer already exists 
file integrity checksum failed for "var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_xlog/000000010000000000000002"
```

Then I deleted that file (and more) from the container, committed the change, and tried to push the new image. I got the same error.

Is there some way to push up my image without pushing up the commit that contains the broken file? Any insight into why the new commit fails in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, that looks like a local daemon error prior to contacting the registry, so I very much doubt there is anything we will be able to do on our side.  That said, if you reach out to us as Jake (jsand) suggests, we can hopefully try to help you resolve the issue.